# Play framework handling session state

Tags: scala, session, playframework-2.1

I have a Webapp that is built on top of the Play framework and Scala. It is about presenting the user with a set of questions with each question having a set of answers. Some of the questions have radio button types an answers and some have check boxes as answers. When the user clicks start test, I call the controller, fetch the list of questions with its answers and return the result as a case class to the view template. I now need to maintain the state of the test as the user answers each question. He can go previous, next and I need to keep track of all the questions that he answered.

Coming from a Java EE background, I thought I can store the case class in the session and manipulate it in my controller. But that unfortunately does not look like that as the Play framework's session is a key value pair of String, String and not a String, Object. I'm now stuck with my app and since my experience with the Play framework is limited, I would like to ask for suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no state at all in Play framework so if you want to keep some data across multiple HTTP requests its handy to use Session scope that actually creates cookies with key/value pair (String, String) and they are limited to 4KB size.

My suggestion is to do it with Json, Play-json library is awesome. IF you have models with JSON [Read/Write/Format](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) combinators than its simple.

```
Ok(render(Questions)).withSession("answers" -> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(Answer)))
```

Reading a session value can be done like this:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
      session.get("answers").map { answers =>
        val jsValueAnswers: JsValue = Json.parse(answers)
        val answersModel: YourAnswerModel = Json.fromJson(jsValueAnswers) 
        Ok("Got previous answers and created session cookie with them")
        .withSession("answers2" -> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(answersModel)))
      }
    }
```

Hope this help you a bit.

Cheers

Comment: The problem is that I need to store the entire test in the session and not only the answers for the current question that the user sees. The question that the user sees has a set of answers which he will select one and submit to the server. I should then take his answer for that question and update my Test object against that question. I'm just wondering on how I could leverage Json to do this. Can you please elaborate a bit as it is not enough for me to store the current answer for the question that will be rendered!

Comment: Well everything depends from the model of your objects, you can write your own Reads/Writes/Format for the objects or use Macro Inception.

case class Answer(id:Long, value:String)
case class TestObject(id: Long, List(Answers))
implicit val answerRead = Json.read[Answer]
implicit val answerWrite = Json.write[Answer]

Comment: Made a mess with the previous comment :) Im new here :)

So,
in your case transforming the session value from string to json than to object on every POST/GET and update the value is not a good solution imo so I suggest you to go with the James suggestion and use memcached.

Answer (score 9):

Play only supports Strings for sessions because it stores all session state in cookies - this means Play nodes can scale without the need for any sort of clustering/state sharing tech.

If the data you want to store is small (less than 2k), then just serialise it into JSON, or it sounds like in your case, even simpler would be to serialise it into a comma separated list of answers.

Otherwise, you can store it in a cache such as memcached or redis.

Comment: Is memcached sort of a database? I've never used it. From the name of it, it looks like it is sort of a cache that I can use to store key, value pairs that mimic a Session and store my objects there. Is it meant for that purpose. I will explore on that bit.

Answer (score 4):

Play is a framework designed to be stateless, so you do not find any concrete concept of server side session. Of course, this is not strictly prohibited, if you need it, as in this case, you can use a server-side technology (cache or database) as a container for your items and Play-cookie session for storing the access key string.

This is an example of storing object using Play Cache:

```
import play.api.cache.Cache
import play.api.Play.current

val key = UUID.randomUUID.toString
Cache.set(key, yourModel, 0)
Ok.withSession("answer_key" -> key)
```

and this is an example of retrieval:

```
import play.api.cache.Cache
import play.api.Play.current

val key = session.get("answer_key").getOrElse("none")
val yourModel = Cache.getAs[ModelClass](key).getOrElse(//whatever you want if not exists)
```

Comment: The problem with the Cache approach is that there is no guarantee that the data will be there even after specifying a timeout for the object to live in the cache. So I do not want to trust the Cache.

Comment: I don't believe it is a real problem. Play uses [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) as default implementation, it implements a persistent disk store which stores data between VM restarts. A similar behavior you have in JEE web session.
Using cookie you are limited to 4 Kb for your serialized data, using cache not.

Comment: Why do you think that it is not a real problem? The idea behind Play's cache mechanism is to retrieve objects that are requested frequently and is not intended as a replacement for a session. Take a look at the link: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.3/JavaCache the very first paragraph says that the data in the Cache might go missing! Just for this reason, I do not want to trust it.

Comment: I think it is not a real problem in your case. But I understand your argument, you may use the database and cache for optimization purposes. Of course as an alternative to cookies (cookies do not consider suitable as containers of data).