# How to handle session using Scala Play framework?

Tags: scala, session, playframework-2.0

I have user login feature in my application. I used Scala Play Framework as controller. I create sessions using `withSession('userId'->userIDValue)` for different users. My application has a feature that there will be one super user and super user can delete user. Now what happens is that if super user deletes a user but that user is logged in then that user's session is running till cookie of browser expires. Play Framework is stateless; is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: This might be of help (I hope): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20773809/497398

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play framework handling session state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772841/play-framework-handling-session-state)

Comment: Is it okay to remove the deleted user session on the next request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On incoming requests, I think you need to verify that a user is still active on the Play side, and not just only trust the session.

If that's an expensive operation, e.g., you have to make a database call to verify if a user is still active, then maybe you can use the Play Cache API. If you only have one Play server instance, then it should be pretty easy -- you can just set something in the cache when the super user deletes a user, and have the cache item expiration be longer than your cookie expiration. If you have multiple Play server instances, then it's tricker. :)