# using guice to inject runtime constructed instance

Tags: java, session, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice

I have an application in Play Framework Java where I let users login, and create a session to allow multiple requests.

Session data is accessible through `Http.Context` in the Controller. But I want session data to be accessible in other classes as well.

What I want to do is construct an instance of a class like `SessionData` in the controller and inject this instance in other classes where I need to access session data.

How can I achieve this? What type of Guice dependency inject should I be looking at?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772841/play-framework-handling-session-state This might help.